# Using R to count number of pixels in raster file for which there are at least one point object present

Tags: raster, r, vector, clip, multipoint

I am trying to count the number of pixels in a raster file for which there are at least one point object present in R. I think this would be easy but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I am new to spatial analyses and finding the proper terminology to describe what I am hoping to achieve is challenging.

**A Visual Representation of the Problem**

Here we have a hypothetical raster with a multi-point vector overlaid. There are 10 pixels in the raster, 3 of which have points associated with them.
[image: A raster with a vector of points overlayed]

**Ideal Outcome**

I want to write some code in R that, given this hypothetical scenario, would return a value of 3 indicating that 3 of these pixels in the raster file have a point object present.

Do you have any tips or tricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a data frame of coordinates:

```
points <- data.frame(x=runif(50), y=runif(50))
```

and a raster:

```
rast <- raster(xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1, res=0.05)
```

you can use `cellFromXY` to find the grid cell associated with each point, and thus the number of unique grid cells.

```
length(unique(na.omit(cellFromXY(rast, as.matrix(points)))))
```